# Particle system instances moving/changing in rendered result?

Tags: particles

I have emitted lots of plants and trees by using a hair particle system emitting a collection.
But when I review the rendered result some of the instanced objects change/move slightly from frame to frame. Like if Blender seeds the emitting.
Any one know anything about this?

I tried making instances real before rendering which solved the issue, but this is a really time consuming task which also makes the Blend-file huge in size (!?).

Any good ideas here...?

Comment: Try to bake particles

Comment: You cant bake hair can you? The cache-option isn´t there as with emitting.
I´ve seen some solutions with UV-mapping from a hair-partical system, but thats not what I wish to do....

Comment: Yep, try to use particle edit than. It should make a freeze of particles. I had no issues with that than I was working with the similar scene though. You can also use Geometry nodes as well

Comment: Have you have "Hair Dynamics" disabled ?

Comment: Do you seem to have anything like the Hair "Seed" value animated?

Comment: Hair dynamics is disable yes. No animations on seed. 
What do you mean with "particle edit"?